# Merging Data-table rows using VB.Net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am merging the data table rows into single table and make sum of each column into one row. This is the following table

```
srno    Product        Gross    Finalamt    Paid
1       Car             90000     0          0
2       Bike            81000     0          0
2       Bike            9000      2800       0
3       Alloy           9720      2820       0
4       Motercycle      9720      5000       0
4       Motercycle      10         20        10
```

Want to Merge the lines and make it to unique rows. for this i am suing this code

```
Dim first4ColGroups = From row In TBL
       Let first4colums = New With {
        Key .col1 = row.Field(Of String)(0)
        }
       Group row By first4colums Into RowGroup = Group

Dim tblUnique = TBL.Clone()  ' creates an empty table with the same columns '
For Each grp In first4ColGroups
    Dim row As DataRow = tblUnique.Rows.Add()
    ' row.SetField(0, grp.first4colums.col1)
    row.SetField(1, grp.RowGroup.Sum(Function(r) r.Field(Of Decimal)("Gross")))
    row.SetField(2, grp.RowGroup.Sum(Function(r) r.Field(Of Decimal)("Final")))
    row.SetField(3, grp.RowGroup.Sum(Function(r) r.Field(Of Decimal)("Paid")))
Next
Return tblUnique
```

Here i Got The Error : **Specified cast is not valid.**
Give me the Solution of that

> > > Output Required

```
 1  Car         90000   0       0
 2  Bike        90000   2800    0
 3  Alloy       9720    2820    0
 4  Motercycle  9730    5020    10
```

Comment: What is the datatype of the columns Gross, Finalamt and Paid in the original datatable TBL?

Comment: It's integer datatype....

Comment: Then why _r.Field((Of Decimal)_?

Comment: Dim mytble = New DataTable()
        mytble.Columns.Add("product", GetType(String))
        mytble.Columns.Add("column1", GetType(Integer))
        mytble.Columns.Add("column2", GetType(Integer))
        mytble.Columns.Add("column3", GetType(Integer))
        mytble.Columns.Add("column4", GetType(Integer))
        mytble.Columns.Add("column5", GetType(Integer))

Comment: After Changing it the error comes **Specified cast is not valid.**

Comment: Change it to  row.SetField(1, grp.RowGroup.Sum(Function(r) r.Field(**Of Integer**)("Gross")))
**Error Remains the Same - Specified cast is not valid. **

Answer (score 0):

Here a sample with your data and with error fixed. The main problem in your code is the correct use of datatype of your input fields. You group by "srno" and this is an integer field not a string. Finally the Sum is on Integer fields not on Decimals.

As a side note, remember that when working with money you should use the Decimal datatype to get exact calculations, in particular if your sums involve decimal values.

```
Sub Main
    ' Your input data as example
    Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
    dt.Columns.Add("srno", type.GetType("System.Int32"))
    dt.Columns.Add("Product", type.GetType("System.String"))
    dt.Columns.Add("Gross", type.GetType("System.Int32"))
    dt.Columns.Add("FinalAmt", type.GetType("System.Int32"))
    dt.Columns.Add("Paid", type.GetType("System.Int32"))
    
    dt.Rows.Add(New Object() {1, "Car", 90000, 0, 0})
    dt.Rows.Add(New Object() {2, "Bike", 81000, 0, 0})
    dt.Rows.Add(New Object() {2, "Bike", 9000, 0, 0})
    dt.Rows.Add(New Object() {3, "Alloy", 9720, 2800, 0})
    dt.Rows.Add(New Object() {4, "MotorCycle", 9720, 5000, 0})
    dt.Rows.Add(New Object() {4, "MotorCycle", 10, 20, 10})
    
    ' Now let's group by srno and Product, note that srno is an int not a string
    Dim first4ColGroups = From row In dt
    Let firstCol = New With {Key .col1 = row.Field(Of Int32)(0)}
    Let secondCol = New With {Key .col2 = row.Field(Of String)(1)}
    Group row By firstCol, secondCol Into RowGroup = Group

    Dim tblUnique = dt.Clone()  
    For Each grp In first4ColGroups
        Dim row As DataRow = tblUnique.Rows.Add()
        ' recover info from srno and product
        row.SetField(0, grp.firstCol.col1)
        row.SetField(1, grp.secondCol.col2)
        ' Sum by Int32 not decimal
        row.SetField(2, grp.RowGroup.Sum(Function(r) r.Field(Of Int32)("Gross")))
        row.SetField(3, grp.RowGroup.Sum(Function(r) r.Field(Of Int32)("FinalAmt")))
        row.SetField(4, grp.RowGroup.Sum(Function(r) r.Field(Of Int32)("Paid")))
    Next
    

End Sub
```

Another problem in the original code is the column indexing on the cloned table. The field in the second position (index 1) is the Product field, a string field where the code tries to store the sum of the third field (index 2). The error happens also on the following fields.

Comment: It is not working..while executing the sql query when put it into the data table Gives the same Error **Specified cast is not valid.**.. The Above Datatable will filled with the sql query. **Like mydable = getdata("sqlQUERY")**.. It is  not working,